# How do I make the statusbar transparent on iOS without removing it in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have looked in multiple places for a solution with my statusbar in my Ionic 3 application. On iOS it seems when I call statusbar.hide it simply removes the objects but keeps the placeholder. You can see it in the image below:

[image]

How do I make it transparent but keep the objects? I want the time and numbers to be there, but the statusbar itself to be transparent.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/jeneser/ionic-super-bar?

Comment: I haven't. But it seems to be focused on Android and my problem is on iOS. I was hoping for a solution within Ionic but I will have a look at the ionic-super-bar.

Comment: `StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent()` should work for ios apparently

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ionic native plugin [**status bar**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) here.

```
styleBlackTranslucent()
Use the blackTranslucent statusbar (light text, for dark backgrounds).
```

Here is the [**original repo for more details**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#statusbarstyleblacktranslucent).

Comment: This still does not solve it. It makes it semi transparent but still very visible.

Comment: I think this is the max you can go with this plugin.  To set Translucent With Black Text you can use this combination. `this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();`